# Generating Wordlist, Python Script

Tags: python

this is my first post in Stack Overflow and i am new to python(this is not my code, I found it in a programming magazine).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#letter_changer.py by dr@g
import sys
def replace_chars(line,dic_words):
 for i,j in dic_words.iteritems():
  line=line.replace(i,j)
 return line
letters={‘8’:’th’,’3’:’ks’,’4’:’ps’}
f=sys.argv[1]
filename=open(f,’r’)
for line in filename:
 new_line=replace_chars(line,letters)
 print new_line,
filename.close()
```

This is a script which is used to enrich a wordlist, it is supposed to read a string, change a letter into another(line 8) and create a new entry for that string. Each line of my dictionary contains one entry in each line.
After running that script i got the following error:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character ‘\xe2′ in file letter_changer.py on
>   line 8, but no encoding declared; see
>   http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

After some research on the internet i realized i should use this piece of code at the beginning of my script:

```
# vim: set fileencoding=utf-8 :
```

(but i don't understand why, since i only used English characters)

After fixing that i had this problem on line 8: letters={‘8’:’th’,’3’:’ks’,’4’:’ps’}

> File “letter_changer.py”, line 8
>   letters=letters.replace(‘8’:’th’,’3’:’ks’,’4’:’ps’) ^ SyntaxError:
>   invalid syntax

The solution might be simple but i am new in python, any reply would be useful, even some tips and general guidelines

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a question of *English* characters, but a question of *ASCII* and quote characters. The file itself contains non-ASCII quote characters on lines 8 and 10, but because they are not ASCII quote characters, even if you tell Python the file is UTF-8, it still won't recognize those things as strings. Compare:

“Smart” quotes:

```
letters={‘8’:’th’,’3’:’ks’,’4’:’ps’}
f=sys.argv[1]
filename=open(f,’r’)
```

ASCII quotes:

```
letters={'8':'th','3':'ks','4':'ps'}
f=sys.argv[1]
filename=open(f,'r')
```